# Remove transform from svg OR Get Java awt components from SVG path

Tags: java, swing, svg, awt, inkscape

I have a svg image, where multiple path elements are grouped like this:

```
 <g
   id="gbase-7-2"
   transform="rotate(180,1066.40705,-904.8082)">
  <path
     sodipodi:nodetypes="ccccc"
     id="basetroc-1-5-8"
     d="M 245.83838,-1232.793 308.95904,-1342.1212 498.32103,-1232.793 403.64003,-1123.4648 Z"
     style="color:#000000;display:inline;overflow:visible;visibility:visible;fill:#ffcd9e;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:5;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-dashoffset:0;stroke-opacity:1;marker:none;enable-background:accumulate"
     inkscape:connector-curvature="0" />
  <path
     sodipodi:nodetypes="ccccc"
     id="basetroc-2-8-7"
     d="M 498.32103,-1232.793 687.6830099999998,-1123.4648 561.4416799999999,-1014.1366 403.6400299999999,-1123.4648 Z"
     style="color:#000000;display:inline;overflow:visible;visibility:visible;fill:#d18946;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:5;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-dashoffset:0;stroke-opacity:1;marker:none;enable-background:accumulate"
     inkscape:connector-curvature="0" />
```

and so on. Every path is a field from a chessboard. Overall all the groups (and for that the path) draw a hexagonal chessboard.

Now I want to know the coordinates of every field, because of i wanna know which field is clicked in a Swing/AWT Java application with the picture in the background. The problem is that all the groups are transformed with a rotation.
Is there any way to get the "real coordinates" of every piece?
Thank you very much :-)
[Chessboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ORK7d.png)

I tried this to remove any translation:
https://github.com/Klowner/inkscape-applytransforms
It draws a working svg, but the path are looking like this:

```
 <path
         id="basetroc-1"
         d="M270.96338 617.6461C270.96338 617.6461 334.08404 508.3179 334.08404 508.3179C334.08404 508.3179 523.44603 617.6461 523.44603 617.6461C523.44603 617.6461 428.76503 726.9743 428.76503 726.9743C428.76503 726.9743 270.96338 617.6461 270.96338 617.6461C270.96338 617.6461 270.96338 617.6461 270.96338 617.6461"
         style="stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-width:5.0;stroke-opacity:1;fill-opacity:1;color:#000000;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke-dashoffset:0;visibility:visible;stroke:#000000;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-miterlimit:4;marker:none;stroke-dasharray:none;overflow:visible;enable-background:accumulate;display:inline;fill:#d18946" />
```

Comment: I already considered batik, but I am not sure this is the right tool since i just wanna know the coordinates.

Comment: Maybe this can be useful to you: https://inkscape.org/~Klowner/%E2%98%85apply-transforms